# Openerp information messages

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Is it possible to create information message with options like **proceed** or **cancel** in OpenERP ? If it is possible how to create one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a js web module to do that.
Create `script.js` under `/module_name/static/src/js/` which contains:

```
openerp.module_name = function(instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    /* For example */
    instance.web.FormView.include({
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wizard with cancel and proceed button within